# How to find straight line segments nearest to a straight line segment?

Tags: image-processing, geometry, computer-vision, line

consider an image matrix in which i have multiple line segments. And i have information's like start point, end points, length of the line segment, centroid and slope of all those line segments. In this scenario how do i find line segments that are nearest to a particular line segment. Also once i got nearest line segments is it possible to detect rectangles if they exist? .An example image is in this link [sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wpqmmiw9t4qhx63/20140410_160756-1.jpg).

Comment: You are mixing straight lines (infinite extent) and line segments (interval on a line). Please be specific about what you need. Line/segment or segment/segment distance ? [Line/line distances are 0, unless parallel.]

Comment: all of them are line segments only.  I need to find the line segments which are nearer to a particular line segment @YvesDaoust

Answer (score 0):

The geometry of segment/segment distance is not so simple.

Imagine two line segments in general position, and dilate one of them. I mean, draw two parallel segments at a distance `d` and two half circles of radius `d` centered on the endpoints. This is the locus of constant distance `d` from the segment. You need to find the smallest `d` such that the other segment is hit.

You can decompose the plane in three areas: the band between the two perpendiculars through the endpoints, and the two outer half planes. You can clip the other segment in these three areas and process the clipped segments separately.

Inside the band, either the segments intersect and the distance is zero. Or they don't and the distance is the shortest distance between the line of support of the first segment and the endpoints of the other.

Inside the half planes, the distance is the shortest of the distances between the considered endpoint and both endpoints of the other segment, and the distance between the endpoint and the other segment, provided then endpoint projects inside the other segment.

ALTERNATIVE:

Maybe it is easier to use the parametric equations of the two segments and minimize the (squared) distance, like:

`Min(p, q) ((Xa (1-p) + Xb p) - (Xc (1-q) + Xd q))^2 + ((Ya (1-p) + Yb p) - (Yc (1-q) + Yd q))^2` under constraints `0 <= p, q <=1`.

Comment: In your first para what do you mean by smallest d such that the other segment is hit ? and i have drawn what u have said in first para let me know am i correct @Yves

Comment: Let me see your drawing

Comment: Quite correct. If you increase `d`, at some point you will meet the other segment.

Comment: on fine. Is there some good material to read about all these ? I dont know which math book to look into can u suggest some material ? @Yves

Comment: Check my other solution and read about "elementary vector calculus".

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to encode all the points in homogeneous coordinates [x, y, 1]<sup>T</sup> since this creates a symmetric relations between lines and points. Namely, in homogeneous coordinates the intersection of two lines l1 and l2 is a point p=l1xl2, where x means vector product. By the same, coin a line that passes through two points p1, p2 is l=p1xp2. Line that lie on a segment can be expressed as l=p1xp2=[a, b, c]<sup>T</sup>. The line equation then will be l<sup>T</sup>.p=0 or in Cartesian coordinates a*x+b*y+c=0

As for your task, there are two cases:
1. segments cross and then their intersection can be simply calculated as l1xl2;
2. segments don’t cross and then the closest points between two lines is the closest point between two of their 4 endpoints. To calculate 4 possible distances and choose the smallest distance between a line segment x1 and x2 and a point x0 use this formula: (x2-x1)x(x1-x0)/|x2-x1|

Comment: thanks for the idea i thought about using homogeneous coordinate system but i didnt find any good material with examples to understand it completely. If you know any book or website for reading about it please suggest me @Vlad

Comment: The best book for this and for Computer Vision in general is “Computer Vision” by Simon Prince (worth buying) http://www.computervisionmodels.com http://web4.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/s.prince/book/book.pdf; if somebody recommends you “Multiple View geometry” by Hartley and Zisserrman - it is classic but very badly written. Szeliski book is not deep enough (http://szeliski.org/Book/). Otherwise it depends on a section you are interested in.

Comment: try this for your problem: http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~fussell/courses/cs395t/slides/L3(ProjGeom).pdf

Comment: Thanks man i was trying to understand by reading multiple view geometry only it was quite hard though will look into that book @vlad

Answer (score 0):

Let the segments be `AB` and `CD`, and running parameters along them `p` and `q`, such that `0 <= p, q <= 1`.

Using vectors, the squared distance between any two points on the segments is given by:

```
D² = (AC - p AB + q CD)²
```

Let us minimize this expression by zeroing the derivatives wrt `p` and `q`:

```
AB.(AC - p AB + q CD) = 0
CD.(AC - p AB + q CD) = 0
```

When `AB` and `CD` are not parallel, this implies `AC - p AB + q CD = 0`, which gives you the intersection point by solving a 2x2 system, and the distance is zero.

But it can turn out that `p` (or `q`) falls out of the allowed range, let `p < 0` (or `p > 1`). In this case, we recast the problem with `p = 0` (`p = 1`). This amounts to finding the distance `(A, CD)`.

```
D² = (AC + q CD)²
```

yielding

```
CD.(AC + q CD) = 0
```

even easier.

And if it turns out that `q` is also out of range, let `q < 0`, we end up with the distance `(A, C)`:

```
D² = AC²
```

Similarly for the other out-of-range cases.

In case of parallel segments, the 2x2 system is indeterminate (both equations are equivalent). You need to solve:

```
CD.AC - p CD.AB + q CD² = 0
```

It suffices to try all four combinations with `p/q  = 0/1` and see if the left hand side takes different signs. This proves that there exists a solution and the distance is the same as distance `(A, CD)`. Otherwise, the answer is one of the endpoint-to-endpoint distance.